# Error: The Serverless Function "shopwise/wsgi.py" is 70.17mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, deployment, vercel

I am trying to deploy Django Project on Vercel and this error appears.

[image]

Here is vercel.json:

```
{
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "shopwise/wsgi.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python",
            "config": {
                "maxLambdaSize": "15mb",
                "runtime": "python3.9"
            }
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "shopwise/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

How I solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some requirements from requirements.txt and redeploy again
as the package size is crossing the limit (50mb on Vercel).

I was also facing the same issue then I tried above and it worked for me.